# Basic concept for manipulating offline data

Tags: c#, json

I'm pretty new to C# and have never used JSON. I'm starting to research JSON because I need a way to store data offline and I'm restricted to either JSON or XML (Corporate red tape). I'm trying to wrap my head around the basic concept of using JSON files in C#.

What is the flow chart if you will for manipulating data in a JSON file.

Lets assume I'm using a console application to scan a folder for all files and add the full file path to a JSON file along with write time and size, then come back later and iterate over the JSON data checking to see if the file exists, if not mark the file as deleted in the JSON file.

Do we: Load the entire file into memory, iterate over it, make a change(add/change/delete data), write the entire file back to the disk (File.WriteAllText)?

Comment: `Newtonsoft.Json`. Read it is as an object structure, manipulate it like any other C# object, then re-serialize it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here is what you are after](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

It is a library called Json.Net made by newtonsoft. It allows you to parse json into an object, and also serialize it back to json.

File reading and writing would remain the same. The difference being that once you have loaded all text from the file, you would call: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonString)` and then when saving you would call you preferred method of writing text to a file, and the string you would pass would be the result of `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objectInstance)`

Comment: Thanks, I've already been looking into that library but what I'm missing is the fundamentals. Was I correct by saying load the entire file into memory make all of my changes then write the entire file back? Or do I read and write incremental changes?

Comment: The second part of my answer answers that. When dealing with a file with JSON.net, you would load and parse the whole file, then save it all at once.You could do it incrementally, it really depends what you are after.